# How can I override Entity in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have one table for which I am creating two entities.
One entity is used in my one core bundle which is used for many projects.

For new project I am creating new bundle and I want to add one more column in that entity.
Can anyone please guide me how can I override entity in other bundle.

Comment: I am not clear. Is this entity mapped to your database? If so does the database already have the new column you are trying to create?

Comment: I am trying to create new column from entity2.

I.e.
I have table "user"
For this table I have created parent entity with 5 fields.
Now I want to add additional fields and for that I can't modify my parent entity for some reason or technical design.

So, I need to create another entity for the same table and I need to override parent entity.
I will add field in child entity which will be updated in db.

Comment: You can extend your original parent User entity

Comment: Is your problem solved? If you came up with a better solution then please share it with us and accept it as an answer, so that it helps future users. Or mark the answer as accepted so that it helps future users

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your original User entity to something like this.

```
namespace XXXX;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use XXXXX as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="newProperty", type="string", nullable=false)
     */

    private $newProperty;
    .....
    .....
}
```

This will have all properties from your class `BaseUser` and you can have additional properties in this new class that you are trying to create. You can add set and get methods here too.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for extending entity and it is working fine.
But now I have an issue when i tried to update schema using command 
It will give an error of duplicate entity.

Comment: @AshishBhanderi I believe that should be asked as a new question as the problem is separate then the problem you have asked in this question.